# change the y axis Label interval in core plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-plot

I implemented core plot library for scatter graph in my app. But I want show the Y  Axis Labels like 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,.. and plot the graph accordingly.

When I change the interval of y Label as follow by multiplying with 25 as shown below

```
NSInteger majorIncrement = 2;

NSInteger minorIncrement = 1;   

CGFloat yMax = 10.0f;// should determine dynamically based on max price    
NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
for (NSInteger j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement) {
    NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrement;


    if (mod == 0) {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
        NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j*25);  **//multiply with 25**`



       label.tickLocation = location;
        label.offset = -y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;

        if (label) {

            [yLabels addObject:label];
        }
        [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];

    } else {
        [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];

    }
}
y.axisLabels = yLabels;    
y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
y.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;
```

But when the graph is ploted , it shows me wrong.

**e.g.** if my score is 150 then it start plot as 150/25=6th point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the orthogonalCoordinateDecimal, To determine the point where your graph starts

```
 CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
   y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(150/25);
```

further more ,setting the plotRange,

```
 CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;   
   plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:(150/25) length:25];
```